# How does String.codePointCount() function work

Tags: java, string

suppose i have this example

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This".codePointCount(0, 4));

}
```

output is 4 
and if instead of 4 i put 3 output will be 3 
basically output is

> 0-3 or generally |firstIndex - secondIndex|

Don't know how it works
can you please give an example where output is different then

> |firstIndex - secondIndex|

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you read its java doc?

Comment: did not understand java doc

Comment: Do you know what a code point is, as opposed to a character, byte, or grapheme? (No? [Start here.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)) This is an advanced Unicode method. If you're interested in the ins and outs of Unicode, give us an idea of what your current knowledge level is. If not, don't worry about it -- you won't need this method in day-to-day Java code.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I have to admit that having read the javadoc, I'm unclear about what this function does beyond tell you that 4-0=4.  The javadoc doesn't appear to explain this method well.

Comment: @PhilipCouling  As John mentioned it is an advanced Unicode method. Without understanding what code point is, I wouldn't expect anyone to understand this method on its own. But you can easily follow to javadocs of other related methods such as `String#codePoints`, `Character#toCodePoint`, `Character#isSurrogatePair`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman i just finished java online course so i m beginner

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Thats fine. Surely that suggests the OP has a genuine question that needs explaining.  Perhaps explaining how a code point does not simply count as 1 in the index would answer the OP's question.  If an OP doesn't know what they don't know that's a BAD reason to down vote a question.

Comment: It will be difficult to explain what this method does without including a long explanation of various Unicode intricacies. I suggest you either (a) go read up on Unicode, starting with [the link I provided](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), and then continuing from there with Google searches about the terms you don't understand; or (b) for now, forget about this method. As a beginner, you don't need it. Hell, I'm not a beginner, and I don't need it, either.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, but this is explained in literally every resource that discusses code point concepts, which on its own a pretty sizeable read, especially if you include historical significance (which you should). It is far better to just type that into some search engine and read couple of articles about it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  That's precisely my point.  Answering this cannot be a simple "RTFM" as others have suggested.  The OP has a genuine question which has a complicated and nuanced answer.  Definitely an UP vote not a DOWN vote.  Or are we now downvoting any questions because their answer is too complicated?

Comment: Lets assume we have `String str = ""`. When we invoke `str.length()` we get as result `4` because each of this symbols is created by two chars (surrogate pair) and `length()` returns amount of characters not "symbols". For `str.codePointCount(0, 4)` result is `2`. Result will also not change if we remove one character from surrogate pair, or simply start counting from indexes which din't hold full pair but only part of it. So for `str.codePointCount(0, 3)` or `str.codePointCount(1, 4)` or even `str.codePointCount(1, 3)` we also get `2`.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, I did not downvote anything, mind you. However, I do think this is not really a good question, because what that really should've been saying is "What is a CodePoint?", and most correct answer to that question is a link to "ISO 10646", not a detailed explanation. This site is not an encyclopedia.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  Perhapse.. But again, you don't know what you don't know.  Lately SO seems to be very aggressive towards people because they don't know the answer to their own question./

Comment: i did not get one thing why i got 3 down votes ?? i did not know so i asked :(

Answer (score 6):

From the javadoc:

> Returns the number of Unicode code points in the specified text range of this String. The text range begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the char at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length (in chars) of the text range is endIndex-beginIndex. Unpaired surrogates within the text range count as one code point each.

Java uses Unicode to represent text (characters).  Unicode gives every character a number called a "Code point".  There are different ways to write these numbers in bytes, java use "UTF-16" (2 bytes per character).  Unfortunately there are too many characters for 2 bytes.  IE more (a lot more) than 65,535.

To get round this UTF-16 uses 4 bytes (2 pairs of 2) for code points with very large numbers.  These are known as surrogate pairs.

Annoyingly java can make this confusing because it treats a 4 byte character as if it's 2 characters.

Example (credits @Pshemo): `""`  This string has 2 characters (a strawberry and a peach).  Technically it has 2 code-points, one for the strawberry, one for the peach.  But if you try this out you will see java says the length is 4.  Because each one is a is a "surrogate pair".

For further reading look at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16
This discusses *surrogate pairs* as mentioned in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses UTF-16 for its internal character and String representation. In UTF-16 a single Unicode character is represented one or more 16 bits CodePoints.

EG. The number of characters is not always the same as number of CodePoints.

See: [Java notes on Unicode, for EG `Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

### EDIT

On the contrary, a single Unicode CodePoint can consist of multiple 16 bits characters...